# HTTP Delete of /a/{id_a}/b/{id_b} becomes /a/{id_a}/b/{id_b}/a/{id_a}/b/{id_b} in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've a servlet in SpringMVC that is working fine in general implementing a REST Api, but I get a strange error when I try to delete a sub-resource.

Saying I have:
- users as the parent resource
- addresses as the child resource

If I create (POST), update (PUT) or retrieve (GET) address everything is ok, but when I try to delete it I receive a 404 not found and looking at the log I see

```
 servlet.DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:1218) - Rendering view 

[org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4'; URL [users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'api-dispatcher'
 view.AbstractView (AbstractView.java:377) - Added model object 'id_user' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4'
 view.AbstractView (AbstractView.java:377) - Added model object 'id_addresses' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4'
 view.InternalResourceView (InternalResourceView.java:207) - Forwarding to resource [users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresseses/4] in InternalResourceView 'users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4'
 servlet.DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:838) - DispatcherServlet with name 'api-dispatcher' processing DELETE request for [/rest-local/rest/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4]
 handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:246) - Looking up handler method for path /users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4
 handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping (AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:254) - Did not find handler method for [/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4]
 servlet.DispatcherServlet (DispatcherServlet.java:1114) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest-local/rest/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4] in DispatcherServlet with name 'api-dispatcher'
 servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:991) - Successfully completed request
 servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:991) - Successfully completed request
```

It's like for some reason I don't understand at a some point it append the relative path two times and of course the final path is not handled and I got a 404 Not found.

In the codebase this is the only situation when I try to delete a sub-resource, for all the existing resource DELETE is working, only in this case I see this strange behavior (the code is exactly the same for this resource and for the others).

The server side mapping is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id_user}/billing-addresses/{id_address}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView deleteBillingAddress(@PathVariable("id_user") String idUser,
                                             @PathVariable("id_address") String idAddress,
                                             HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                             Principal principal)
```

And I'm testing it with:

```
curl -i -X DELETE \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language:it" \
 'http://localhost:8081/rest-local/rest/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does this work fine in a simple rest tool? Can you post the client side code?

Comment: I'm using DHC (a rest client plugin for Chrome), the code it uses is: curl -i -X DELETE \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language:it" \
 'http://localhost:8081/rest-local/rest/users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/billing-addresses/4'

Comment: show us your controller mapping

Comment: I've updated the questions with server side mapping and client testing code.

Comment: Are you showing the right log ? Your log shows a request to users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/***shipping-addresses***/3 but you use curl with users/544e6b02300429b462c6b8ea/***billing-addresses***/3

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I've corrected the log. I have two twins methods one for shipping one for billing. Both of them show the same error. I've corrected for coherence (thanks).

Comment: Lets see the body of that delete method too. Are you adding a forward/redirect to the ModelAndView? Is it a relative redirect (and thus, pulling in the current path)?

Comment: The body is empty. Both for request than for the response. So it would probably be better to make the method void. But since the debugger is not even enter in the method the problem here is that SpringMVC makes something before entering my codebase.

Comment: Do you have a `@RequestMapping` on the controller class holding the method `deleteBillingAddress`? Your log entry starts with 'users/544e6.....' and your curl entry also has 'users/544e6b02....' but your mdelet method's `@RequestMapping` is "/{id_user}/billing-addresses/{id_address}" there is no 'user' prefix in it. I don't think this method is being called at all.

Comment: @Dan your message made me in the right direction. I was returning an empty ModelAndView object and this fact in some way influenced (negatively) the behaviour of Spring. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was returning an empty ModelAndView object instantiated with `new ModelAndView()`.

Now I changed it returning:

```
new ModelAndView(this.userMapperView, DATA_FIELD, billingAddress);
```

Not sure is this the best way, but at least now it works.